# Vital signs of unfamiliar software are present in safe mode: TopBuzz in Galaxy Note8

Tags: malware, cache, safe-mode, samsung-galaxy-note-8

In **Device Maintenance** system app on Samsung Galaxy Note8, there is a [**TopBuzz** cache shown when caches are being cleaned](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/206172). **Also in the safe mode.**
It reappears as a cleanup item every few minutes together with **System cache** item and they show 82 MB to clean up.

[image]

Since nothing like that is installed, I originally thought this is a sign of a malware, but after rebooting to the safe mode, the behavior continues and both items are re-appearing every few minutes in 82 MB size.

**Is *TopBuzz* normal part of Note8 built-in software or is it possible that it somehow got into the phone later? How can I determine what is happening here?**

Additional details:

- The phone is not rooted.
- Android 8.0.0.
- 5 anti-virus scanners did not find any issue with **TopBuzz**.
- I reviewed the entire app list in the safe mode and found nothing like that.
- Despite the name on the above screenshot, I did not find a public or hidden cache called TopBuzz using *SD Maid* app. Any other caches shown by *SD Maid* contain only few kilobytes after cleanup, 82 MB is nowhere to be found. But TopBuzz + System cache still show that 82 MB size in Device Maintenance app.

---

Update: Samsung support replied me that "TopBuzz is not a part of their device".

Comment: No idea, but [here's the app on Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.android.article.master). If you're familiar with ADB, you could use that to check whether it's installed (like `adb shell 'pm list packages'|grep ss.android`).

Comment: Please, if someone else with Note8 sees this, kindly drop a note here.

Comment: Search for "buzz" in SD Maid's AppControl, make sure you have system apps included via settings. It will search both app names and packagenames. Could possibly be an instant app which shows almost no where...

Comment: Yeah, so I downloaded topBuzz when you are looking try to look for something like com.ss.android.article.master or anything starting with com.ss.android.article. The app has a very high amount of permission request at about 48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 and have the same problem as you with TopBuzz showing up in the storage clean but unable to find it anywhere in my phone.

I tried the SD Maid app but that did not help. However, I did try Clean Master which I have used in the past with my old phones becuse it does work better than the built in storage clean (but uninstall it when im done with it because im sure that it slows down the phone to make you use it from time to time) and that appears to have fixed the problem.

I ran Clean Master, then ran the system storage clean and did not see TopBuzz, ran Clean Master again for good measure and then uninstalled it. It has only been a few hours but I have ran the storage clean a couple times and have not seen TopBuzz at all. If you still have this problem try this out and let me know how it goes!

Comment: I am glad to accept this as an answer because it seems that it worked for me. Installed, cleaned (without anything reported), uninstalled and the Topbuzz seems to be gone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung support has replied me that "TopBuzz is not a part of their device".
So this is most likely a sign of an utilized exploit where [a malware can compromise even non-rooted device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207046/can-a-malware-compromise-safe-mode-of-non-rooted-device).

Comment: If you are keen on identifying the package name and app name for TopBuzz, can you give the output of `adb shell cmd package list packages -f -i -U`? Use a code paste service such as Pastebin to share the output. That TopBuzz is either a malware itself or is installed by a malware. See https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=VnhPXLOONZmv9QOi1KqwAQ&q=%22topbuzz%22+%22malware%22&oq=%22topbuzz%22+%22malware%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.5520.7983..8379...0.0..0.151.1381.0j10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0.QMdcisYx1xw

Comment: @Firelord – thank you. I am new to Android. I must once sit down and put my hands on `adb shell`. Currently, I am acting only as "ordinary user". :)

Comment: Oh yeah. I'm sorry I missed that you are new to Android. Please take your time and get acquainted with adb, if you are keen on digging into this further. I cannot promise that I would be able to find the culprit but I can offer my assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost a year late, but I've also recently noticed TopBuzz appearing on that Device Maintenance screen as well, starting a few days after I installed TikTok, about a month ago. Finally guessing at a connection between the two, I did a bit of Googling to discover that TopBuzz and TikTok are both products of the Chinese company, ByteDance (which seems very fond of MidWord-capitalization in their PortManteaus.) Thus, I'm guessing that TikTok downloads with a non-interactive TopBuzz client for producing in-app ads, creating an advert cache labeled TopBuzz.

If anyone can come up with a method for verifying this, I'll add my findings.